# How to export (or share) a highlighted PDF from Kindle Reader?

Tags: kindle, pdf, kindle-fire

I can email a PDF to my Kindle Fire Device. I can highlight and take notes in that PDF. I can export the notes and the highlighting.

BUT I see no way to share/export the PDF with the highlights.

Use Case:

1. Send PDF to my Kindle Reader.
2. Read, highlight, take notes.
3. Share the highlighted PDF with *another* of my Kindles, or ideally, my online Kindle Reader.
   Is there any way to do that?

Comment: 4 Years later: I have the same issue.
It is crazzy

Answer (score 5):

Kindles' have USB Drive Mode. which allows you to export all of your notes (except pictures):

1. Plug the Kindle to your computer.
2. Open the Kindle folder.
3. Go to the `documents`.
4. Get the `My Clippings.txt` file, which has all of your notes & highlights.
5. Eject the Kindle.

> Note: `My Clippings` is a `txt` file, which is quite hard to read. I would highly recommend you to use a third party service like [Clippings](https://www.clippings.io/) or [Readwise](https://readwise.io/) to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

it seems as if the only way at the moment is to share each highlight via facebook directly from the kindle reader (under go to ---> notes )

It s a total shame. The information is stored in the .sdr folder with the name of your pdf in the .pds and/or .pdt files. However I have no idea nor found a solution how to use them.

If you find one I would be interested

Comment: If you share it that way, do you actually end up with a highlighted PDF on another device?
(I.e., share notes and share pdf and get a highlighted pdf on different device?)